# How to read EnumValueOptions from Protobuf in C#?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I want to read fields of type "EnumValueOptions". All examples I have found are related to languages other than "C#".

There is a protocol:

```
syntax = "proto3";   
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto"; 

extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
   string enum_name = 51234;
};;

message Options {
  enum Profiles{
        A = 0 [(enum_name) = "AAA"];
        B = 1 [(enum_name) = "BBB"]; 
        C = 2 [(enum_name) = "CCC"];
  };
  Profiles profile = 1;
}
```

How to read "enum_name" in code C#?

expecting:

```
foreach(Profiles profile in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Profiles)))
{
    string name = ????; //name in ("AAA","BBB","CCC")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm programming in C# - still pretty new to this protobuf stuff

If you have the following proto file extending the EnumValueOptions:

```
extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
  string Value = 101;
  bool AutoEnrol = 102;
}
```

Protobuf will produce a *EnumValueOptionsExtensions* class through auto-generation.
To access it use EnumValueOptionsExtensions.Value or EnumValueOptionsExtensions.AutoEnrol, per the C# code sample a little later/below.

Then in the same or another proto file, create an enum with the following:

```
enum SystemRoleType {
  ReservedRole = 0 [(Value) = "SystemRoleType.ReservedRole", (AutoEnrol) = false];
  Administrator = 1001 [(Value) = "SystemRoleType.Administrator", (AutoEnrol) = false];
  Editor = 1002 [(Value) = "SystemRoleType.Editor", (AutoEnrol) = false];
  ContentCreator = 1003 [(Value) = "SystemRoleType.ContentCreator", (AutoEnrol) = false];
  User = 1004 [(Value) = "SystemRoleType.ContentCreator", (AutoEnrol) = true];
}
```

Again, this will produce a *SystemRoleTypeReflection* class through protobuf auto-generation.

Then in C#, include your namespaces accordingly (that also includes: Google.Protobuf.Reflection) and then you could do something like the following in C#

```
EnumDescriptor SystemRoleTypeTypeEnumDescriptor = SystemRoleTypeReflection.Descriptor.FindTypeByName<EnumDescriptor>(typeof(SystemRoleType).Name);
foreach (SystemRoleType system_role_type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SystemRoleType)))
{
    EnumValueDescriptor enum_value_descriptor = SystemRoleTypeTypeEnumDescriptor.FindValueByNumber((int)system_role_type);
    var selector_value = enum_value_descriptor.GetOptions().GetExtension<string>(EnumValueOptionsExtensions.Value);
    var auto_enrolment = enum_value_descriptor.GetOptions().GetExtension<bool>(EnumValueOptionsExtensions.AutoEnrol);
}
```

Updated (2021-12-01):
I put a tiny VS solution together today, that you can open in Visual Studio Community 2022 (.Net 6 / C# 10) and run the example in a console app: github.com/kibblewhite/EnumValueOptions-gRPC-Example

Comment: not created / no post-orders for namespase to EnumValueOptionsExtensions

Comment: Hey Gardes, with the amount of information you have provided here, I can assume one of two things.
1. You have not defined the option "csharp_namespace" in your proto files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669740/grpc-messages-defined-in-proto-file-are-not-available-in-final-dotnet-assembly
2. Maybe the Grpc.Tools package is not correctly configured or not present/missing from the nuget packages?

Something else you can try, is visit the "obj" folder (BaseIntermediateOutputPath), see if the *.cs stub file has been generated.

Comment: One last thing could be that the protobuf xml node entry is missing from your *.csproj. The protobuf node in the *.csproj file should look something like this:
```
<Project ...>
  <ItemGroup>
      <Protobuf AdditionalImportDirs="Protos" Include="Protos\Common\EnumValueOptions.proto" GrpcServices="none">
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Sorry, that is the best I can offer with the amount of information provided.

Comment: Actually, I can go one step more, I put a tiny VS solution together today, that you can open in Visual Studio Community 2022 (.Net 6 / C# 10) and run the example in a console app:
https://github.com/kibblewhite/EnumValueOptions-gRPC-Example

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf doesn't generate c# codes for enum value options, so if you want to retrieve these values, you need edit the source at `src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_doc_comment.cc`.

Here is an example

```
void WriteEnumValueDocComment(io::Printer* printer, const EnumValueDescriptor* value) 
{
    WriteDocCommentBody(printer, value);
    
    // Example code to prepend c# attribute like '[Custom(name: value)]' before a enum field
    const Message& options = value->options();
    const Reflection* reflection = options.GetReflection();
    std::vector<const FieldDescriptor*> fields;
    reflection->ListFields(options, &fields);
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string name = fields[i]->full_name();
        std::string fieldval;
        TextFormat::PrintFieldValueToString(options, fields[i], -1, &fieldval);
        printer->Print("[Custom($name$: $value$)]", "name", name, "value", fieldval);
    }
}
```

Regenerate cs file then you can use [GetCustomAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattribute?view=netcore-3.1) method to retrieve these information.

Comment: very sorry there is no implementation for c #.

Comment: where to call this method?

Comment: It's called by protoc. @Gardes

Comment: Error (active) E0515: cannot be converted to incomplete class "const google :: protobuf :: Message" //const Message& options = value->options();

Answer (score 1):

Proto:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package my.protos;
option csharp_namespace = "My.Protos";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto"; // For enum extension.

extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
    optional string NameDisplay = 50001;
    optional string NameAbbrev  = 50002;
}

enum MyOperation {
    MY_CREATE = 0 [(NameDisplay) = "create"];
    MY_DELETE = 1 [(NameDisplay) = "delete"];
    MY_READ   = 2 [(NameDisplay) = "read"];
}
```

Usage in C#:

```
Google.Protobuf.Reflection.EnumDescriptor descriptor = 
    MyProtosReflection.Descriptor.FindTypeByName<Google.Protobuf.Reflection.EnumDescriptor>(
        typeof(MyOperation).Name
    );

Google.Protobuf.Reflection.EnumValueDescriptor valueDescriptor =
    descriptor.FindValueByNumber((int)MyOperation.Create);

string nameDisplay = valueDescriptor.GetOption(MyProtosExtensions.NameDisplay);
```

Comment: I believe this to be an answer to the question.

Comment: Where to get MyProtosReflection and MyProtosExtensions?